# How to increase the hitbox of a elements on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to hover over a text and display an image then. This works so far, but to be honest the "hitbox" is too small. The image is just getting shown when I actually hover over the text. I would be cool if one could make that hitbox taller. Is there any possible solution for this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('under_line');
    $(this).prev().show();
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('under_line');
    $(this).prev().hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.is_hidden{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.under_line{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="is_hidden" src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" style="z-index:9" width="200px"/>
<span><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></span>
```

I would love to have it like on [this site](http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/386427-top-8-control-full-guide-by-mariohs). Have a look at these tables and then hover over an element like for example like ***Execute***:

[image]

It feels so smooth and nice. I already looked with the developer tool into the css of this but couldn't find anything that helps me..

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you could try adding some padding and negative margin to your CSS like so:

```
span {
   padding: 30px;
   margin: -30px;
}
```

This will make the element 30px larger on each side, but the negative margin will allow the surrounding text to not be pushed away by the same 30px amount.

Comment: You actually cannot add padding and margin to a span since it does it's display state does not allow this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - here is a [working example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/2c06bmb9).

Comment: @FrankProvost Could you please elaborate on your statement (especially since you downvoted my answer which now includes a working example)?

Comment: you're right - my fail - will change vote as soon as possible

Comment: No worries. Thanks for following up!

Comment: I edited my question :) Maybe you know then what I mean :P

Comment: Note that this will, of course, affect the layout around it in some cases - a solution that wouldn't, would need a bit more code.

Comment: it's really disapointing that CSS doesn't decorelate the hitbox zone from the layout, which would simplify everything a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and it is actually hard to tell what is the best solution without knowing the context, so heres a basic proposal:

```
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

You should ofcourse not style the span element in general, but this fits to your example. Better would be to wrap your text in an element and set the style there.

The padding will increase the "hitbox" / size of your element.

Better Solution:

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hovering').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('under_line');
    $(this).prev().show();
 },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('under_line');
    $(this).prev().hide();
 });
});
```

css

```
.hovering {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="is_hidden" src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" style="z-index:9" width="200px"/>
<p class="hovering"><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p>
```

Comment: edited my question to show you how it look / feel like

Comment: well for this you will need a little more. the element is positioned to the mouse - maybe have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/VagxT/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using pure css. Put the image and text in a div and detect when the div is hovered over, then hide/show the image using the `:hover` selector.

### HTML

```
<div id="hoverhere">
  <img src="http://random-ize.com/lorem-ipsum-generators/lorem-ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg"/>
  <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 img{
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -200px;
  top: -100px;
}
#hoverhere{ 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#hoverhere:hover img{
  display: block;
}
#hoverhere:hover p{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/L7L1bep6/1/

I updated my answer to mimic the site you linked more closely.

Comment: I edited my question with an example on how it should look / feel like :)